# How to emulate a firmware image on qemu

Tags: emulation, qemu, firmware

I have a firmware image. On using the binwalk command, I get that it is a cramfs file system. I have extracted the file system using binwalk. How do I find out the architecture of this file system (eg. arm, x86, mips, ... )so that I can emulate it on QEMU?

Answer (score 1):

If you've managed to extract the filesystem contents, you should be able to use the Linux `file` or `objdump` commands to identify what architecture the executable files were compiled for.

However, note that "CPU architecture matches" is not sufficient to emulate a full firmware image (ie including bootup code and the kernel) on QEMU. You need to know the exact hardware that the firmware runs on, because it will expect to be running on a system with devices (serial port, timers, interrupt controller, etc) at particular hardware addresses and with specific functionality. Unless the QEMU model matches these, the firmware won't get very far in booting, even if the CPU type matches. And QEMU probably doesn't have a model of whatever specific embedded device this is.

You might be able to run the userspace filesystem on QEMU with a kernel built for a machine type QEMU does support, but this will only work to the extent that the userspace programs don't actually care what hardware they're running on, so depending on what you're trying to achieve it might or might not help.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. I have a few questions. First, how do I go about building a qemu model to emulate the full firmware image? Second, by running the userspace file system on qemu, do you mean copying the contents of the firmware file system into an already running vm in qemu, and then chrooting into the firmware file system? I tried this, but I ended up with the error ```chroot: can't execute '/bin/sh': Permission denied```