# How to emulate a firmware image file using qemu

Tags: qemu, binwalk

I could see that this file was a firmware image compiled by arm.
The image is a bootloader image, and I tried emulating it through qemu, but the error below occurred. How can you solve it?

> Wrong image type 5, expected 2

Comment: Far too little detail to say exactly what is going on here, but in general you cannot expect to run "some random firmware for a particular Arm device" on QEMU and have it work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054022/how-to-emulate-a-firmware-image-on-qemu/67056437#67056437 has some more detail on why.